# If $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix. and $B=A'A$, then what can be said about the eigenvalues of $AB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

If $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and $B=A'A$, then what can be said about the eigenvalues of $AB$?

No form of $A$ is given; then how to proceed ?

Can this problem be at all solved? If anyone can help . . .

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for?  Some form of inequality, perhaps?

Comment: In general, knowing the eigenvalues of $A$ is not enough to deduce the eigenvalues of $AA'A$ without additional information.  If we knew, for instance, that $A'A = AA'$, then we would be able to deduce the eigenvalues of $AA'A$.

Comment: I edited your question to $\LaTeX$ify your math, and correct some grammar and punctuation.  Cheers!

Comment: With $A'$ you mean $\text{ }^tA$?